# Unable to re-index in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, database, ce-1.7.0.2

My magento indexing page showing processing only.

I  tried http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-resolve-magento-reindexing-errors-in-your-magento-store/#

not working, could anyone please suggest a solution for this

[image]

actual error after clicking on reindex data

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable' not found in /home/damarokiatest/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php on line 37

Comment: Check running processes on your server, indexing might actually be running.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this script in your root folder let us assume filename:reindex.php

Place it in your root folder

```
<?php
//Following 3 lines will load the magento admin environment.
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('admin');
umask(0);

// to reindex the processes we require their ids
// for default magento there are 9 processes to reindex, numbered 1 to 9. 
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

// Sometimes there are processes from our custom modules that also require reindexing
// We need to add those ids to our existing array of ids
// To know the id of process, just hover on each process in your
// admin panel-> System-> Index Management
// You will get a url : admin/process/some_id/......
// this id corresponds to the process

$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,390,391,478);
foreach($ids as $id)
{
//load each process through its id
try
{
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($id);
$process->reindexAll();
echo "Indexing for Process ID # ".$id." Done<br />";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

After that run www.domain.com/reindex.php

it will take 5 - 10 min

Comment: "Indexing for Process ID # 1 Done"   i gots this after  runing www.domain.com/reindex.php

Comment: it will show all id's then logout and login your admin panel

Comment: actually when i tried to re-index  i am getting this error Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable' not found in /home/damarokiatest/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php on line 37

Comment: this is front end or back end error

Comment: backend error  when i click on product prices reindex data

Comment: i don't think what is the problem just try front end

Comment: i allso have a  similar related problem no able to edit system>configuration>catlog>catlog

because i wanted to change store view price scope from website to storeview error is There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 592119701004

Comment: and in the log report          i am getting this                                                                           a:5:{i:0;s:87:"Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_catalog_search_type";i:1;s:1770:"#0 /home/damarokiatest/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')